# How to find an equivalent of $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp{(-x^n)}dx$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

It's an exercise, I need to find an equivalent of :

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp{(-x^n)}dx$$

I tried this :
Let $x=u^{1/n}.$ Then $dx=\frac{1}{n}u^{1/n-1}\,du,$ so :
\begin{align}
\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-x^n}\,dx & =\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^n}\,dx-\int_0^1 e^{-x^n}\,dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{+\infty} u^{1/n-1}e^{-u}\,du-\int_0^1 e^{-x^n}\,dx\\
& = \frac{1}{n}\Gamma(1/n)-\int_0^1 e^{-x^n}\,dx = \frac{1}{n}(n+o(n))-1+o(1)\\
& = o(1)
\end{align}

I try to multiply by $n$ but I am stuck here. One person told me that there will be a euler constant after that (I doubt it). Yet I don't know how to show it.

I would like first prove that there is a constant $c\neq 0$ such that this integral multiply by $n$ equals to $c$. Then try to find it.

Comment: Your substitution gives $$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}u^{1/n-1}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$ Now, you can show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}u^{1/n-1}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\int_{1}^{\infty}u^{-1}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u=-\operatorname{Ei}(-1)\approx 0.219384.$$

Comment: Oh ! I see ! That was easy !

Answer (score 0):

Using the incomplete gamma function and the exponential integral function
$$I_n=\int\exp{(-x^n)}\,dx=-\frac{x }{n}E_{\frac{n-1}{n}}\left(x^n\right)$$

$$J_n=\int_{1}^{\infty}\exp{(-x^n)}\,dx=\frac{1}{n}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$$

If we  expand $\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$ as a series for large value of $n$, the constant term is $c_0=-\text{Ei}(-1)$ as already given by @Sangchul Lee in comments.

What is difficult is to simplify the next since they involve more and more complex Meijer G-functions such as
$$c_1=G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$
$$c_2=G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1 \\
 0,0,0,0
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ and so on. Less compact forms involve hypergeometric functions.

Making their decimal values rational
$$n\,J_n=-\text{Ei}(-1)+\frac{59}{603\,n}+\frac{23}{646\,n^2}+\frac{3}{271\,n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

For $n=10$, the above would give $J_{10}=0.0229524$ while the exact value is $0.0229536$